# JQueryMobile saving a form to a txt file

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile, save

I'm building a app with jquerymobile and I've a page which is a form where I have to fill some info about the field job I have done so I can save it, instead of arriving to the store and fill the paperwork by guessing the time of arrival and the time of the finish.
So, I want to fill the form and when I tap on submit, it saves a txt or another file type on the android phone.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

When user clicks the save button

```
var form_1;
var jsonString;
function saveFormState() {
         form_1 = $("#form").find("select,textarea, input").serializeArray();
         jsonString = JSON.stringify(form_1);
         console.log(jsonString);

         getFSToSaveForm();
}

function getFSToSaveForm(){
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0 ,function(fileSystem){
            var entry=fileSystem.root;
                entry.getDirectory('myForms', {create:true, exclusive:false}, function(dirEntry){
                    dirEntry.getFile('formToSave.json', { create: true, exclusive: false}, saveToJsonFile, onError);

                }, onError);
        }, onError);
    }

    function saveToJsonFile(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer){
            writer.onwrite = function (evt) {
                console.log("Wrote to file: " + jsonString);
            };
            writer.write(jsonString);
        }, onError);
    }
```

If you want to restore:
+Read the file and save the read text on a vaiable
Then use some Jquery.

```
var jsonString;
function getFSToRead(){} //You can find the code in the cordova API http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html

function restoreFormState() {
    var newObjectArray ;
    newObjectArray = JSON.parse(jsonString);

        console.log(newObjectArray.length);
        jQuery.each( newObjectArray, function( i, field ) {
        $( '#' + field.name).val(field.value);
         });    
}
```

Hope that helps